# How to setup up build matrix with containers on Github Actions

Tags: github-actions

I want to run test against distros that are not available as GA [runners](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/virtual-environments-for-github-hosted-runners#supported-runners-and-hardware-resources). In my case, containers are fine.

How I describe a build matrix with containers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here an example using four different docker images

```
name: ci

jobs:
  job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        container: ["ubuntu:bionic", "fedora:31", "opensuse/leap:42.3", "centos8"]

    container:
      image: ${{ matrix.container }}

    steps:
      - name: checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v1
```